# CSS transition on JavaScript changing style

Tags: javascript, css, transition

Hello I have a div and close button on this div

and simple CloseMyDiv function to hide my div

```
function CloseMyDiv(){
  document.getElementById('myDiv').style.display = 'none';
}
```

How can I add animate like css transitions

Comment: Define the animation in a class and add the class to myDiv

Comment: Purely in CSS you can use animation in the class as described here -https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can't animate the `display` property, but you can change the [opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) of the element. Like @Gerard said in the comments, use a CSS class. So, something like this.

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div')
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
    div.classList.toggle('hidden')
})
```

```css
div { transition: 0.5s }
.hidden { opacity: 0 }
```

```html
<button>Show/hide</button>
<div>i am a div.</div>
```

In case you do not want the `div` taking up space while its hidden, you can add, say `transform:scale(0)` or `height:0` to `.hidden` as well.

Comment: Thank you, but i need somentig like rolling down effect

Comment: My bad then, that is what I was able to gather from the question. If you can please comment here on what is the end result you're looking for, I can try to help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

As @rmn mentioned, you cannot animate the display property and you don't want your div to take the space after it closes, so you can apply the below sample code:-

HTML -

```
<div id="myDiv">Just a div</div>
<button id="btn" type="button">Close Div</button>
```

CSS -

```
div{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:white;
  color:black;
  border:1px solid black;
  transition:all 2s;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.closed{
  height:0px;
  width:0px;
  border:0;
}
```

Javascript -

```
function closeMyDiv(){
  document.getElementById('myDiv').classList.toggle('closed');
}

document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function(){
  closeMyDiv();
}
```

Here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/m07nhzsk/13/

Hope this helps. Cheers !!

Comment: Thank you the link is ok, but in my case animation doent work, i dont know,

Comment: My code is complicated but classList.toggle works ok but  animation doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you want a sliding animation, you can try using a very short jQuery code (it's still Javascript, though).

```js
$('#closeBtn').click(function(){
    $('.toBeClosed').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toBeClosed">Div element</div>
<button id="closeBtn">Close</button>
```

You can easily remove the click function if you want the code to run without clicking.